# CKEditor updating parent textarea from child window

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, parent-child

I have a parent window with a textarea and when the parent window opens  it also opens a child window.  The user answers a question that is posted back into the parent textarea when the user clicks on the submit button that triggers the javascript code below.  However this code does not update the parent/textarea since I started using CKEditor.

Any suggestion on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the current javascript code in the child window.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.focus();

   // update parent window
   function updateParent() {
      var r = myform.reason.value;
      opener.document.getElementById("notes").value = "Reason: " + r;
      window.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding it to the textarea which is hidden, NOT the ckeditor instance. Get the instance of the ckeditor and call insertText() to add text. Call insertHtml() for html.

Example

```
opener.CKEDITOR.instances.notes.insertText("Reason: " + r);
```

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY!  Thank you very much for taking the time to help!